# Unable to get Simple Name for Types Inside Nested Object Hierarchy

Tags: java, scala

I have the following code:

```
object Repro {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println(classOf[Foo.Bar].getSimpleName)
    }

    object Foo {
        trait Bar
    }
}
```

When I run it I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Malformed class name
    at java.lang.Class.getSimpleName(Class.java:1322)
    at Tests$.main(Tests.scala:3)
    at Tests.main(Tests.scala)
```

Is this the intended behavior? If so, why? What am I missing here?

I'm using JDK 1.8.0_25 and Scala 2.11.7.

Comment: There is open issue here https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2034

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are hitting a very old Scala bug: [SI-2034](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2034).

You could use Scala reflection instead of plain Java reflection, and achieve the same thing:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> val t = typeOf[A.B.type]
t: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = A.B.type

scala> t.termSymbol.name
res11: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol#NameType = B
```